# ...furniture, books, "a laptop", paintings, and lamps are flying across the room

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

> Men's clothes, designer furniture, books, **a laptop**, paintings, and lamps **are** flying across the room.

My question is if I can put *a laptop* among the things when I end the sentence with *are*? Does *are* refer to all the things?

Comment: Yes: "My shoe, a book and the chair are flying across the room." But "designer furniture is flying across the room" because furniture is a singular noun, even when it means several items.

Comment: @WeatherVane -- Your comment could be the core of a good answer.